# androidで予測変換機能を実装したい

Tags: java, android

[android AutoCompleteTextViewにSimpleCursorAdapterを使う](http://programhhyy.hatenablog.com/entry/2014/11/18/234807)

を参考にしてsqliteのデータをアダプターに入れて実行したのですがsqlのデータの一覧が表示されるだけで実装したい機能とは違っていました。

```
    AutoCompleteTextView inputTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoInput);DatabaseOpenHelper helper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(this);
    SQLiteDatabase database = helper.getWritableDatabase(); 
    Cursor cursor = database.query("person", new String[]{"rowid as _id", "name"}, null, null, null, null, null);
    CursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            this, 
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
            cursor,
            new String[]{"name"},
            new int[]{android.R.id.text1},
            0);
    inputTextView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

[【android アプリ 開発】　AutoCompleteTextView　作成](http://timblue.blogspot.jp/2011/01/android-autocompletetextview.html)
のソースのように文字を入力するとString配列の中にある一致文字があるデータのみを表示させ選択できるプログラムのstring配列をsqliteの列に置き換えたいのですが方法がわかりません。
どなたかご教授をお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FilterQueryProvider.runQuery(CharSequence constraint)`をフィルターした`Cursor`を返すように実装し(LIKE述語を使うなどして出来るでしょう),`CursorAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider (FilterQueryProvider filterQueryProvider)`で設定してやれば実現できます. `constraint`で渡される文字列は入力された文字列です.

以下は動作確認をしたコード.`dHelper`はインスタンス変数であるという設定

```
adapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
    public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
        String str = constraint.toString();
        System.out.println(str); // constraintが変化する様子を確認
        Cursor cursor = dHelper.getReadableDatabase().query(
                "person", new String[]{"rowid as _id", "name"},
                "name LIKE '' || ? || '%'",new String[]{str},
                null, null, null);
        return cursor;
    }
});
```

Comment: 具体的にはフィルターをしたCursorを上の文のどこで実装すればよいですか。
使用例をご教授できるのであればお願いします。

Comment: もうちょっと待ってから編集すればよかったですね・・・。`inputTextView.setAdapter(adapter);`の前に上のコードを書いて動作確認しました.

Comment: ありがとうごさいます。
無事解決しました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

冒頭のページにて、最下部に解決方法が書かれていますが、

```
inputTextView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

の上の行に、

```
adapter.setCursorToStringConverter(new CursorToStringConverter() {
        @Override
        public String convertToString(Cursor cursor) {
            return cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
        }
    });
```

を挿入するとうまくいく、と書かれておりますのでお試しください。

Comment: この処理はAutoCompleteTextViewのアダプターに入れた内容を選択する処理なので実装したい機能とは違います。
sqliteでキーワードの一部だけ入力で文字で始まる単語や入力文字が含まれている単語を羅列して表示してくれる機能を実装したいのです。